# Symfony Validation of DateTime fails due to not being string?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-validator

I have the following for:

```
formFactory->create(FormType::class);
$form->submit(['startDate' => new \DateTime('2020-01-01')]);
```

Note: if I use `'startDate' => '2020-01-01'` then it works.
Within FormType I have the following:

```
$builder->add('startDate', DateType::class, [
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
]);
```

The config options are as follows:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Event::class
        ]);
    }
```

And in the Event entity I have a field like this:

```
/**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ODM\Field(type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $startDate;
```

Yet I keep getting this error and not sure why?

```
"startDate":["This value is not valid."]
```

I have Symfony 4.4.10.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're trying to pre-set data, `submit` is the wrong tool for the job. It's literally meant to handle a submission in normalized form (array with scalar values and arrays). Instead use the second parameter for [`FormFactory::create`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/63d886f7cba2ce38785e01a9f19da24246506478/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php#L28) to preset data:

```
$event = new Event();
$event->setStartDate(new \DateTime('2020-01-01'));
$form = $formFactory->create(FormType::class, $event);
```

Comment: In FormFactory? there is no createForm in formFactory

Comment: oh, you're right, I was referring to ControllerTrait. it's just the second parameter to `create`. my bad ;o)

Comment: Then I remove the submit() right, and now I have this though;
`Cannot check if an unsubmitted form is valid. Call Form::isSubmitted() before Form::isValid()` As i want to check if the values are correct

Comment: I'm really confused what your use case is, when you're using forms without a submission ... can you clarify in your question? And if there's no submission, why would you want to validate? In that case, btw. a [`ValidatorInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/ValidatorInterface.php) would be better suited to directly validate... ? `$errors = $validator->validate($event);`

Comment: Hmm maybe I am also not so sure :)
But I have received my data (converted some of it like the string date to DateTime and then want to use the form validator to see if the submitted data is there/correct. I guess the form validator doesnt handle complex structures like you said. Good to know.

Comment: do you receive data from a html form or via an api? in both cases there are slightly different approaches. html form: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms and something similar to https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html for api submissions. the form component is smart and you shouldn't have to "prepare" data for it, just pass it an array with scalar/raw data.